# Bash: Add elements to array in for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, arraylist, concatenation

I have a list of hostnames like:

```
hostnames = (host1 host2 host3)
```

Also, I'm trying to resolve these hostnames into IPs:

```
for host in ${hostnames[@]}; do
    var=`doing some stuff`  # It returns IP address with odd spaces
    ips+=`(echo $var|xargs)`  # Removes odd spaces
```

It works, but returns in this format:

```
127.0.0.1127.0.0.2127.0.0.3
```

I expect to have `ips` to make it possible to iterate over it and fetch using indexing:

```
echo ${ips[2]}  # Should return 127.0.0.3

for (( i=0; i<${#ips[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo ${ips[i]}
```

etc.

How to add these IPs in a correct way to make it possible to iterate through these values and extract them via index?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be spaces around the equal sign:

```
hostnames=(host1 host2 host3)
```

To add entries to an array you need parentheses *outside* the backticks:

```
ips+=(`echo $var|xargs`)
```

A simpler way to remove spaces is with `${var//pattern/string}` substitution. It's faster since it avoids unnecessary child processes.

```
ips+=("${var// }")
```